# Keep getting "No member named ptr_fun, bind2nd" for swift project

Tags: c++, swift, objective-c

Im using a swift package for splitting Chinese characters. The project uses Objective-C to encapsulate the C++ and then read it with swift. I downloaded the project from github found here [Chinese Parser IOS](https://github.com/qiwihui/SwiftJiebaDemo). I ran the project and everything worked out fine but when I put the files into my own project I keep getting errors. It keeps saying that certain members are not in namespace std. Such as `ptr_fun , bind2nd`. Here is the code that is throwing the errors. I was searching around and it says that these members where "deprecated" not sure if this has somthing to do with it? I'm not familiar with c++ so not sure what the problem could be? Maybe an xcode problem?

```
inline std::string& LTrim(std::string &s) {
s.erase(s.begin(), std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), 
std::not1(std::ptr_fun<unsigned, bool>(IsSpace))));
return s;
}

inline std::string& RTrim(std::string &s) {
s.erase(std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), 
std::not1(std::ptr_fun<unsigned, bool>(IsSpace))).base(), s.end());
return s;
}[![enter image description here][2]][2]

inline std::string& LTrim(std::string & s, char x) {
s.erase(s.begin(), std::find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), 
std::not1(std::bind2nd(std::equal_to<char>(), x))));
return s;
}

inline std::string& RTrim(std::string & s, char x) {
s.erase(std::find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), 
std::not1(std::bind2nd(std::equal_to<char>(), x))).base(), s.end());

return s;
}
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Because `std::ptr_fun` and `std::bind2nd` were removed in C++17, you need to set the language standard to C++14 or earlier to be able to compile the code verbatim.

Comment: Ah okay got it thank you